# Not being able to output a dynamic array

Tags: javascript

Ok guys. Javascript newbie here. 
Basically, I need to write a basic quiz about music. I need the user to type in the answer they think, and at the end, it outputs the answer they wrote and tells them if its wrong/right.
My logic, was this:

- put questions into an array called questions.
- create an empty array called userAnswers.
- create a function (which is called when a button is pressed) in which
  it loops through the question and everytime it outputs one question
  on the screen, it stores the users answer into a variable called
  answers and this is then transferred into the array we previously
  created, userAnswers.
- create another array called realAnswers in which is holds the real answers to the question and then loop and compare the elements in the userAnswers array. E.g. if realArray[0] == userAnswers[0] then correct else fail etc

But the problem Im facing is the userAnswers array. Ive defined it empty but when the browser enters the for loop, it should populate it with the users answer but it doesn't since I try to print out the array at the end of the loop to see if it contains the users answer but it doesnt print....

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title> Quiz </title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Start the quiz" name="quiz"   onclick="gettingAnswers();" />
<script>

var questions = ["How many times did 50 cent get shot?", 
"What year did Micheal Jackson die?",
"How many awards has Drake recieved as of January 2015?",
"What year did Kanye West win his first award?"];

var userAnswers = [];

function gettingAnswers ()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++)
    {
        var answers = prompt(questions[i]);
        userAnswers[i] = answers;
    }
}

document.write(userAnswers);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

(excuse the questions, couldn't think of anything else....)

Comment: you also aren't waiting for the answers to be collected.

Comment: `document.write(userAnswers);` inside the `gettingAnswers` function. After the loop.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should move the write to the end of the function:

```
function gettingAnswers (){
    for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
    var answers = prompt(questions[i]);
    userAnswers[i] = answers;
    document.write(userAnswers);
}
```

`userAnswers` is an array, not a string.  You probably want to change it to something like:

```
document.write(userAnswers.join("<br>"));
```

which would output each answer, seperated by an html line break.

Comment: thanks for the info. I have one question, why did i have to move the document.write code inside of the function? Why couldn't it be printed on the page when its outside the function because surely it should be populated with the users answers whilst the browser is executing the for loop and therefore I should be able to call it anywhere after the for loop..

Comment: If it's outside the function, it would get called immediately, whereas the function doesn't get called until they click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Move "document.write(userAnswers);" inside the function. I checked and it works.

```
function gettingAnswers () {
   for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
   var answers = prompt(questions[i]);
   userAnswers[i] = answers;
   }
   document.write(userAnswers);
}
```